# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Angewohnheit und Gewohnheit?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Ich lese ein Beispiel, wobei [Gewohnheit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gewohnheit#Noun) durch [Angewohnheit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Angewohnheit#Declension) beschränkt wird, aber ich erkenne keine Abweichung.

> Ja, Ursache dafür ist ganz oft Gewohnheit, eine schlechte
>   Angewohnheit, und in der Folge ist dann die Muskulatur des
>   Stimmapparates zu schwach. Darf ich fragen: Sind Sie Deutscher oder
>   Ausländer?

Gibt es durch die Verwendung von "an" einen feinen, hinzugefügten Unterschied?

Answer (score 3):

*Angewohnheit* is negatively connotated, while *Gewohnheit* is neutral. Smoking is an *Angewohnheit*, getting to bed at 11 is a *Gewohnheit*.
However, this isn't due to the prefix *an-*. That prefix simply focuses on *starting* a habit, while the base verb describes *continuing* a habit.

Why would people speak specifically about the starting with *bad* habits, but not with good habits? Perhaps because we see bad habits as something that requires corrective action, and preventing something is way easier at the start than after a while. But that is conjecture. Certainly the Prefix *an-* in itself is not pejorative.

Answer (score 0):

Der Kniff liegt darin, dass

> eine schlechte Angewohnheit

ein feststehender Begriff für *»ein Laster«* (das Laster) ist, während

> eine schlechte Gewohnheit

einen erst einmal grübeln lässt, ob nicht vielleicht doch etwas anderes gemeint ist. Inhaltlich bedeutet beides dasselbe.

---

Allerdings bedeuten z.B. die Verben *sich gewöhnen* und *sich angewöhnen* nicht dasselbe:

> Er hat sich an das Deutsche gewöhnt.  *(Er versteht Deutsch.)*
>
> Er hat sich das Deutsche angewöhnt. *(Er spricht Deutsch.)*

Comment: "Er hat sich an das Deutsche gewöhnt." bedeutet nicht, dass er das Deutsche versteht, sondern dass er es kennt, es ihn nicht mehr überrascht oder es ihm nicht mehr unangenehm ist.

Comment: Es kam mir vor allem auf den Unterschied an, wie ihn ein Deutschlerner empfinden wird.

Comment: Wenn ich mein Smarphone immer über Nacht 8h auflade, obwohl Techniker empfehlen es nicht zu 100% aufzuladen sondern besser nur zu 80%, dann kann ich das eine schlechte Angewohnheit nennen, oder nicht? Um welches Laster handelt es sich dabei?

Comment: @userunknown Du hast das Laster selber beschrieben. Es geht nicht um ein vordefiniertes Laster (wie in "die sieben Todsünden").

Comment: @Janka Du meinst, der Schüler gewöhnt sich erst an den ätzenden Deutschunterricht, wenn er Deutsch versteht?

Answer (score -1):

'Gewohnheit' bezeichnet den Umstand, dass man etwas regelmäßig tut, es als normal empfindet oder kein Problem darin sieht ("Er hat sich an den Verkehr in der Großstadt gewöhnt.")

'Angewohnheit' bezeichnet ein Verhaltensmuster, dass man angenommen hat ("Der Kaffee am morgen ist eine Angewohnheit von mir.").

Die feste Wendung 'eine schlechte Angewohnheit' bezeichnet ein solches Verhaltensmuster, das man selbst oder andere negativ bewerten und das man trotzdem noch nicht wieder abgelegt hat. ("Es ist eine schlechte Angewohnheit der deutschen Medien, Trumps Kommentare wortwörtlich zu übersetzen.")

Also ja, es gibt einen Bedeutungsunterschied durch den Präfix "an-".

Comment: Etwas regelmäßig zu tun ist doch ein Verhaltensmuster, oder nicht? Wenn ich in den zwei Definitionen Gewohnheit und Angewohnheit vertausche, sehe ich keine falsche Aussage.

Comment: Ein Verhaltensmuster muss nicht unbedingt eine regelmäßige Handlung sein, es kann auch eine eintrainierte Reaktion auf bestimmte Situationen sein, z.B. mit Abweisung auf Nähe reagieren. Des Weiteren habe ich nicht behauptet, dass eine Angewohnheit nicht auch Gewohnheit sein kann.

Comment: Aus A folgt B bedeutet nicht, dass aus B auch A folgt. Meine Aussage umzudrehen, um die umgedrehte Aussage zu bestreiten geht also schon am Thema vorbei. Dazu kommt, dass ein Reaktionsschema, wie das von Dir beschriebene, einer Regel gehorcht und also doch genau das ist: regelmäßig. Und ja, Du behauptest nicht, dass eine Angewohnheit nicht auch eine Gewohnheit sein kann, sondern Du machst eine Aussage zum einen ohne zu sagen, ob oder inwiefern das für den 2. Begriff nicht passt, machst dann analog eine andere Aussage für den 2. Begriff, ohne ihn vom 1. abzugrenzen, aber das war die Frage, …

Comment: … was der Unterschied ist. Es liegt also nahe anzunehmen, dass Du damit sagen willst, dass die erste Definition nicht für den zweiten Begriff und umgekehrt gilt. Das ist sonst Thema verfehlt. Das genau ist meine Kritik.

Comment: @userunknown Definitionen sind Äquivalenzen, keine Implikationen. Ein Begriffsunterschied kann also selbst dann bestehen, wenn eine Implikation erhalten bleibt. Den Rest deines Kommentars verstehe ich leider nicht. Bitte formuliere ihn anders!

Answer (score -1):

In den meisten Fällen werden Gewohnheit und Angewohnheit synonym gebraucht, aber wenn es um Tradition, Brauchtum, Sitte usw. geht, dann passt nur Gewohnheit.

> In unserem Wohnblock ist es zur Gewohnheit geworden, Papiermüll, der
>   nicht mehr in die blaue Tonne passt, daneben zu stellen.